# Is WCF suitable for low-latency persistent-connection local Client/Server applications?

Tags: wcf

So I have tinkered with WCF in the past, and I know that you can use it not only for web services but also for persistent TCP client/server applications, but I never really put it through significant use.

I am looking into creating a  client/server application for .NET that will run locally, that is both the server and multiple clients will run on the same machine. There will not be a huge number of simultaneous connections, maybe 50 at the most. The amount of data that is transferred per request will not be very much, mostly small objects around 40-100 bytes. There will be a lot of different object types, though, so I'd prefer a solution that makes the serialization simple.

The biggest concern is that I will need to send many packets back and forth in quick succession, and I can't afford much latency. Ideally I will need a round-trip of a 100 byte packet to be less than 1ms (assuming no processing time is used processing the data on the server).

I know this is possible with a native Winsock/IOCP-based solution as I have a solution that works for another project, but I have no idea if this is something that WCF can handle, as I have no idea how much processing overhead is involved in each request/response, or what kind of asynchronous IO it uses.

So, do you think WCF could work for this, or will I need to create a lower-level socket-based solution?

Comment: I would still use *a* library - no need to do this "by hand". That being said, there are likely better candidates for this particular than WCF (search for "object request broker" or "rpc" - might be good reads). As far as the encoding, I find that [Protocol Buffers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers) makes a good serialization target for this sort of use case - it's fast, compact, and supports both reflection/POCO (as in [Protobuf.NET](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)) and generated type implementations (as in [ProtoGen](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/)).

Comment: You know, I was just looking at Protobuf a few weeks ago for something else, and somehow it didn't even cross my mind here. I may very well go this route, since I believe Protobuf.NET should be binary compatible with the native C++ implementation of protobuf, which would be a nice bonus.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use NamedPipes for inter-process full duplex communication.  Very fast and does not go over tcp.  Only works if everything is running on the same machine.

[This article](http://dotnet-experience.blogspot.com/2012/02/inter-process-duplex-communication-with.html) should help.

Comment: I didn't know WCF supported named pipes. Do you happen to know if it's possible to set the integrity level of the pipes in WCF? One of the requirements I have is that the server will be running as a high-integrity Windows Service, and I will need to communicate to it from a low-integrity process.

Comment: @Gerald This will help; exactly what you're doing:
https://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/chrisdi/archive/2011/02/15/named-pipe-communication-with-low-integrity-clients.aspx